Issues calculating SMDs after applying IPTW weights
I get the exact same standardized mean differences (SMDs) before and after applying inverse probability of treatment (IPTW) and stabilized IPTW weights to my data. I reproduced this below using the cobalt package to create a balance table. I also tried manually calculating the weighted means, SDs, and SMDs which gave the same results.
Is this normal? If so, why? Applying weights to the population should intuitively change the weighted mean value for the covariates, so I'm very confused. Thanks in advance!
library('cobalt')
data('lalonde', package = 'cobalt')

# calculate IPTW weights
iptw_fit <- glm(treat ~ age + educ + race, 
                family = binomial(), 
                data = lalonde)

prop_score <- if_else(lalonde$treat == 0, 
                      1 - predict(iptw_fit, type = 'response'),
                      predict(iptw_fit, type = 'response'))

lalonde$iptw <- 1/prop_score

# calculate stabilized IPTW weights
numer_fit <- glm(treat~1, family = binomial(), data = lalonde) # numerator
pn_trt <- predict(numer_fit, type = 'response')

denom_fit <- glm(treat ~ age + educ + race, # denominator
                 family = binomial(),
                 data = lalonde)
pd_trt <- predict(denom_fit, type = 'response')

lalonde$siptw <- if_else(lalonde$treat == 0, 
                        ((1-pn_trt) / (1-pd_trt)),
                        pn_trt/pd_trt)

# calculate SMDs

bal_tab <- bal.tab(treat ~ age + educ + race , data = lalonde,
                   weights = c("iptw", "siptw"),
                   binary = "std", continuous = "std", 
                   stats = c('mean.diffs'),
                   s.d.denom = 'pooled'
) 

print(bal_tab)
```


This is because SMDs (and any balance statistics that involve between group comparisons) are not affected by stabilization of weights. In fact, estimation of treatment effects is not affected by stabilizing the weights either, as explained in this question. The idea that stabilizing weights changes their properties only applies to non-saturated models. For single-time-point treatments, most outcome models are saturated in the sense relevant for stabilization not to have any effect. Computing any balance statistic in which the components are computed within each group separately (which is true of SMDs, KS statistics, variance ratios, ESS, etc.) will not be affected by stabilizing weights.
This is because stabilizing the weights involve multiplying the weights in each treatment group by a constant. In the treated group, this constant is the proportion of treated units, and in the control group it is the proportion of control units. Balance statistics and treatment effect estimates from saturated models are invariant to arbitrary scaling of the weights within each group.
Note that your question said you get the same SMDs before and after applying the weights, but your code only examines balance in the weighted samples; to request SMDs before applying the weights, you need to set un = TRUE; doing so you will see that the weights do affect the SMDs, but your observation that the SMDs are the same for stabilized and non-stabilized weights is accurate and expected as explained above.

That makes sense, thank you!
